# magento Showing Error:500 Internal server Error

Tags: php, magento

I upgraded My magento store form 1.6.2 to 1.7.0.2 but it is showing the **Error:500 Internal server Error** . I changed the File permissions also but it doesn't get solved. Cleaned the cache and sessions but it is not working. Can any body tell me how to Solve the problem?

Thanks...

Comment: Your going to have to give us more than just the HTTP status code if you expect any kind of help

Comment: I am not getting what you want?

Comment: 500 server errors can be caused by a million and one different things, 99% of which actually have nothing to do with Magento. A 500 HTTP status code simply means there was an error on the server. Apache logs, php logs, Magento logs that contain information from the time the bad request was made, will be required to offer any meaningful help.

Comment: i faced this 500 er from magento many times before. most likely some config xml are wrong

Comment: i did not find any error in error_log file located on the root

Comment: @Paul Dinh: what was the problem

Answer (score 8):

By default Mageto switches errors output off. If your php is configured not to log php errors web server will send 500 error in case any fatal error occurs.

You can check errors in /var/log/exception.log and /var/log/system.log or enable output of all errors in your magento installation:

edit your index.php :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and .htaccess:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that actually helped me (after an entire week of fighting of with this)...

> To overcome 500 Internal Server Error :
>
> **change the folder permission of below folder to 777**
>
> - app/etc
> - var
> - media
>
> **change the file permission of below files from 664 to 644**
>
> - index.php (main index file in magento root folder)
> - downloader/index.php

source: http://blog.luutaa.com/magento/how-to-overcome-500-internal-server-error-when-installing-magento/

Answer (score 1):

just execute this command if you are using Ubuntu

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento
```

Comment: First off the location of the Magento home directory will vary, secondly just never do this its totally insecure and you are opening up your server to exploitation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough repuation to comment on the following advice:

> sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento

Never set permisions to 777 - you leave your server wide open to compromise. On apache folders should be 755, files 644. If this isn't sufficient, it probably means an ownership issue or server misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by increasing some values of the fcgid.conf (etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf)

```
FcgidIdleTimeout 3600
FcgidProcessLifeTime 7200
FcgidMaxProcesses 64
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
FcgidConnectTimeout 300
FcgidIOTimeout 180
FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
FcgidIdleScanInterval 10
```